# How to mark the record when the "hollow" in the continuous sequence follows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**The task:** Having the SQL table with the columns `year` and `month` (both year and month as integers; plus the columns with some facts), how can I set the flag for records when the following month is missing?

**The motivation, context:** The user should be filling the fact values for the missing months (think about the planned values of whatever). To make the work simpler, I am displaying an icon at the end of the row in GUI. Clicking the icon will creates the next record in the sense *the next month*. However, the year and month values are part of a unique key. I do not want to offer creating *the next month* if the next-month record is already there. The idea is to show the icon only for the rows where the next month record is not there (to avoid creating a duplicate).

**Example:**

```
year  month  flag      my comment
2020    1     0
2020    2     0
2020    3     1        icon should appear here because the next month (2020/4) should be created 
2020    5     0
2020    6     0
2020    7     0
2020    8     1        icon should appear because the month 9 and 10 are missing
2020   11     0
2020   12     0        December is followed by the next-year January, no icon 
2021    1     0
2021    2     0
2021    3     0
2021    5     0
2021    6     0
2021    7     1        the last record in the sequence -- show icon to create the next month
```

How can I write the query using a single `SELECT` statement? I am using MS SQL 2014 in the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` and some arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lead(year*12 + month) over (order by year, month) = year*12 + month + 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks, Gordon, for the solution. It works nicely. Anyway, why it returns 1 also for the very last record? This is what I want, but what is the explanation. I have read the doc. The `LEAD` returns `NULL` for the record that does not exist (if another default is not explicitly given. So, it compares NULL to some number and that is never equal. Therefore the else branch returns 1. Is that correct?

Comment: @pepr . . . For the last record, the `lead()` returns `NULL` which the expression turns to `NULL` . . . so the condition is treated as false.